# ASP MVC 4/ How to permanently associate the Model with the Metadata file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using ASP MVC 4/ VS 2013, Created Metadata file for Models using tutorial (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation), but upon regenerating the class, the attributes do not transfer nor does the "using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations."

The attributes can be entered manually again to each Model, but will be lost again any time the database is updated / regenerated. Any suggestions on how to permanently associate the each Model with the Metadata file? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you dont must change the classes that EF created, you need to create another file (e.g. ClassMetadata.cs), so you have to class for each entity, the class that EF created, and your class (metadata), but in another file.

Also, if the problem persits, can you show us some code?